# How to make the calendar image respect the disabled property?

Tags: javascript

The below code disables and enables a div (it disables two text boxes). The problem I am facing is that I cannot disable a calendar popup (popup occurs on clicking a calendar image). I can still interact with it.

**JavaScript**

```
function(){ 
  var btnEnableDisable = document.getElementById('enable-disable');
  var divTwoTextBoxDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('two-text-box-div');
  btnEnableDisable.onclick = function(){
    if(btnEnableDisable.value=='Disable'){
      btnEnableDisable.value = 'Enable';
      enableDisableDiv(true)
    }else{
      btnEnableDisable.value = 'Disable';
      enbaleDisableDiv(false)
    }
  }

  var enbaleDisableDiv = function(boolVal){
    for(var key in divTwoTextBoxDiv){
      divTwoTextBoxDiv[key].disabled = boolVal;
    }
  } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="two-text-box-div" id="div2" >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate"   runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCalenStart"  runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ico-cal.gif" ></asp:HyperLink>
        <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="StartDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="hypCalenStart" TargetControlID="txtStartDate"  SelectedDate='<%# Datetime.Today() %>' Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </ajax:CalendarExtender>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate"  runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypCalenEnd"   runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ico-cal.gif"  ></asp:HyperLink>
        <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="EndDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="hypCalenEnd" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" SelectedDate="<%# Datetime.Today() %>" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
        </ajax:CalendarExtender>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2 align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="enable" class="enable-disable-textbox"  OnClientClick="validate(1);" runat="server" Text="Enable" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>        
</div>
<input type="button" value="Disable" id="enable-disable"/>
```

otherthan that all the other are disabled.